# FullCalendar Events show in month and list, but not week and day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

My events show on the month view and on the list view, but not on the week or day view.

I have tried doing 'allDayDefault: false' in the initialization of the fullCalendar, and 'allDay: false' in the attributes of each of my events (both shown below).

```
   //This takes all of my events from a google calendar and puts them in an array to be fed to the fullCalendar
   var eventArray = [];
   var request = window.gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
     'calendarId': 'primary',
     'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
     'showDeleted': false,
     'singleEvents': true,
     'orderBy': 'startTime'
   }).then(function(response) {
     var events = response.result.items;

     var j = 0;
     if (events.length > 0) {
       var eventsArr = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
         var event = events[i];
         var startDate = event.start.dateTime;
         var endDate = event.end.dateTime;
         if (!startDate) {
           startDate = event.start.date;
         }
         if (!endDate) {
           endDate = event.end.date;
         }
         var rowArray = {title: event.summary, start: startDate, end: endDate, id: event.id, allDay: false};
         eventsArr.push(rowArray);
         this.setState({
           eventArray: eventsArr
         })
       }
     } else {
       console.log('No upcoming events found.');
     }

     //This creates my fullCalendar
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listYear'
       },
       views: {
           month: { // name of view
               titleFormat: 'MMMM'
           },
           agenda: {
               titleFormat: 'MMM, DD'
           },
           listYear: {
             titleFormat: ' '
           }
       },
       defaultDate: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today'),
       allDayDefault: false,
       navLinks: true, 
       editable: true,
       nowIndicator: true,
       eventLimit: true, 
       events: this.state.eventArray
     });
```

Does anyone know how to make the events show in week and day view as well?

Comment: You can refer this doc https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/.  defaultView add this option in your code.

Comment: Week view example https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/

Comment: @IrfanAli I'm not sure this addresses the issue.  My agendaWeek and agendaDay views show, but the events on do not show on those views.